# Java redirect all page requests to same JSP file

Tags: java, php, redirect

Is there any way in Java Web such that whenever a request comes a specific JSP page is called?  In PHP i use .htaccess file to redirect all requests to same page. Following is the code I use in .htaccess for PHP apps:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bootstrap.php [L]
```

Does the .htaccess file also works in Java? what is the correct way of doing this in java.

Comment: I think you are looking for response.sendRedirect() in jsp

Comment: Actually i don't want send location header to client. Just want to invoke the same JSP page for any request URL.

Comment: requestdispatcher.forward (...) will not change the URL

Comment: Suppose there is a jsp file named "bootstrap.jsp". The follwoing request comes to server http://myweb.com/images/world.jpg At this request the bottstrap.jsp file must be called and it will further handle the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You should configure a servlet or a filter with the url pattern as wildcard so that any request is handled by the servlet or filter.You can do the following in your web.xml*

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.app.ActionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

In your ActionFilter class implement javax.servlet.Filter and in your doFilter method,simply redirect the response to your jsp.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("myJsp.jsp");

    try {
        requestDispatcher.forward(req, res);
    }
    catch (ServletException e) {
        logger.error("Exception occurred:", e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Exception occurred:", e);
    }
}
```

You can modify this method according to pro grammatically handle your project needs

Comment: But this type of approach will create again another request. To quote @asim-shaq said "Actually i don't want send location header to client. ".

Comment: If that is the case,you have to sue a request dispatcher.I am modifying the code

Comment: a request dispatcher works on the same request and location header will not be sent to client

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess files are for Apache HTTP Server only. For JSPs, you need to configure the url pattern (i.e. `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`) in the web.xml of your Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: I am using eclipse kepler "Dynamic Web Application Project". Can you tell me exactly where I should configure this? I do not see any web.xml file in project.

Comment: WEB-INF/web.xml. Be sure to check the create deployment descriptor checkbox before creating the project . If you did not check it will the xml file will not appear there.